# Motorsport results Database (design problem)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a Motorsports database, but i'm having some difficulties in one of the database table design.

**The problem**:

For each rounds, there are two races, which have different points systems. As of now, i'm storing the points per row (between 20 to 30) per race, but this 
is time consuming, and if i want to change them in the future, it will be a headache to update them all.

I could maintain as is, but would like a better solution.

**Race 1 Example**: (Position. Driver - Points)

1. Driver 1 - 20
2. Driver 2 - 15
3. Driver 3 - 10
4. Driver 4 - 5

**Race 2 Example**: (Position. Driver - Points)

1. Driver 1 - 10
2. Driver 2 - 8
3. Driver 3 - 6
4. Driver 4 - 3

I wanted a table which could have different points systems, which i could afterwards join to the results table so i don't have to store the points manually per race.

A table which would have to store a PointsSystemID, Position, Points.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this?

**Note**: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just have a single Results table with DriverID, RaceID, Position,  RawScore. A Driver table for Driver Details, A Race table for Race Details (including the applicable PointSystemID) and PointsSystemDetails (that would include the definition of scoring calcs). Then you could just join them all together on the appropriate columns and use the calculations to get the Driver's scores for each Race.

Comment: What are the formulas you use to calculate points?

Answer (score 0):

You can create exactly the table you suggest in your question `(PointsSystemID, Position, Points)`

And in your results table, replace `Points` with `PointsSystemID`.

Then to calculate points at SELECT time, just join the two tables on `PointsSystemID` and `Position` and you get the points for each driver in each race.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how your data is structured and what your expectations are. I made the assumption that Race Points were based off of the Driver's Position, and that there were a set amount of points per position for each race.

*Create the base tables.*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DriverDetails ( DriverID int, DriverName varchar(100) ) ;
> CREATE TABLE RaceDetails ( RaceID int, RaceDetails varchar(200) ) ;
> CREATE TABLE PointSystems ( PointSystemID int, PositionID int, PointsAwarded int ) ;
> ```

I split the major pieces of your structure, so that you can add details about each piece without duplicating the data. I also added point values based on the position. Point Values can be changed for each race, and the group of Points can be assigned to different races without having to duplicate.

*Create the primary results table.*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ref_RaceRounds ( 
>     RaceRoundID int
>   , RaceID int
>   , DriverID int
>   , DriverPositionID int
>   , PointSystemID int 
> ) ;
> ```

This is the table that would essentially hold the outcome of each race. If needed, another `RoundInfo`-type table could be created to hold information about the rounds, if needed. This is also where the `PointSystem` that was used for the Race is defined. If a Race changes point systems later, historical points will be kept. If Driver Points will be adjusted when a Race changes points systems, then `PointSystemID` can be moved to `RaceDetails` and the `JOIN` can be adjusted.

*Populate some data.*

> ```
> INSERT INTO DriverDetails (DriverID, DriverName)
> VALUES (1,'Driver1'),(2,'Driver2'),(3,'Driver3'),(4,'Driver4'),(5,'SlowPoke') ;
>
> INSERT INTO RaceDetails (RaceID, RaceDetails)
> VALUES ( 1, 'Race1' ), ( 2, 'Race2' ) ;
>
> /* This is assuming Driver Points are calculated by Race Position */
> INSERT INTO PointSystems (PointSystemID, PositionID, PointsAwarded)
> VALUES 
>     ( 1, 1, 20 )
>   , ( 1, 2, 15 )
>   , ( 1, 3, 10 )
>   , ( 1, 4,  5 )
>   , ( 1, 5,  1 )
>   , ( 2, 1, 10 )
>   , ( 2, 2,  8 )
>   , ( 2, 3,  6 )
>   , ( 2, 4,  3 )
>   , ( 2, 5,  1 )
> ;
>
> /* Race Statistics by Driver */
> INSERT INTO ref_RaceRounds ( RaceRoundID, RaceID, DriverID, DriverPositionID, PointSystemID)
> VALUES
>     (1,1,1,1,1)
>   , (1,1,2,2,1)
>   , (1,1,3,3,1)
>   , (1,1,4,4,1)
>   , (1,1,5,20,1)
>   , (2,2,1,1,2)
>   , (2,2,2,2,2)
>   , (2,2,3,3,2)
>   , (2,2,4,4,2)
>   , (2,2,5,40,2)
> ;
> ```

With the way I set up my points, if a Driver finishes in a Position that doesn't have a Point value, then that Driver will receive `null` points, which can be converted to `0` in the final query.

*Now query by joining up those tables.*

> ```
> SELECT rrr.RaceRoundID
>     , rd.RaceDetails
>     , rrr.DriverID
>     , dd.DriverName
>     , rrr.DriverPositionID
>     , ISNULL(ps.PointsAwarded,0) AS PointsAwarded
> FROM ref_RaceRounds rrr
> INNER JOIN DriverDetails dd ON rrr.DriverID = dd.DriverID
> INNER JOIN RaceDetails rd ON rrr.RaceID = rd.RaceID
> LEFT OUTER JOIN PointSystems ps ON rrr.PointSystemID = ps.PointSystemID
>     AND rrr.DriverPositionID = ps.PositionID
>     AND rrr.DriverID = dd.DriverID
> ```

Which gives:

> ```
> RaceRoundID | RaceDetails | DriverID | DriverName | DriverPositionID | PointsAwarded
> ----------: | :---------- | -------: | :--------- | ---------------: | ------------:
>           1 | Race1       |        1 | Driver1    |                1 |            20
>           1 | Race1       |        2 | Driver2    |                2 |            15
>           1 | Race1       |        3 | Driver3    |                3 |            10
>           1 | Race1       |        4 | Driver4    |                4 |             5
>           1 | Race1       |        5 | SlowPoke   |               20 |             0
>           2 | Race2       |        1 | Driver1    |                1 |            10
>           2 | Race2       |        2 | Driver2    |                2 |             8
>           2 | Race2       |        3 | Driver3    |                3 |             6
>           2 | Race2       |        4 | Driver4    |                4 |             3
>           2 | Race2       |        5 | SlowPoke   |               40 |             0
> ```

I use `ISNULL(ps.PointsAwarded,0)` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to make sure that a Driver receives `0` points if finishing in a Position that isn't assigned a point value.

This could probably be simplified a lot if it was needed, but it could limit the ways in which the query could grow or result in duplicated data. And again, if your requirements are different, this structure will likely change.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=18e95d9755178eed34b4eee1e79f1ab0)*

**NOTE:** You can also easily add a Running Points Total to your query:

- Add `RaceDate` to `RaceDetails`.
- Add `, SUM(ISNULL(ps.PointsAwarded,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY rrr.DriverID
  ORDER BY rd.RaceDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS
  PointsAwarded_RunningTotal` to the `SELECT`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e477dbd2e978f685da59d548d1fe3b15